# Access to different levels in Mongoose with multiple users

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have this model:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: String,
  imagen: [{ 
              title: String,
              author: String,
              index: Number,
              date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
              comments: [{
                         user: String,
                         body: String,
                         date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
                 }]
           }],
  });
```

I know how to set, for example,the author of the image, but I don't know how to search the date of an specified image.

And, If I want to search the images of multiple users, how can I show those images in chronologic  order, as the Twitter's time line. I use EJS as template, and Express.js in the server-side, how can I do that image-timeline? I don't even know how to acces to an specified image date, so, I'm a really beginner with mongoose.

Comment: I think you'll have to use the aggregation framework to `$unwind` the `imagen` array and then `$sort` it and filter it with `$match`.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing dates with the "time" component so if you want to retrieve data for a specific day you have to set an interval for the whole day:

```
var query = userschema.find( 
{"imagen.date": {"$gte": new Date(2013, 1, 7), "$lt": new Date(2013, 1, 8)}});

query.sort({"imagen.date":1}).exec(callback);
```